Divider Generator handshake is not working
I'm a beginner in FPGA programming and I'm trying to implement a noise filter in Verilog on Vivado. I'm doing calculations on the input signal where division is needed, so I'm using the Divider Generator IP to implement the division outside of a module. I'm trying to keep track of my division result with a variable can_go, but when I use it for an if condition, it seems like the conditions are never true. When I don't keep track of my division output, I get a result of 0 anyway. I'm guessing that I'm implementing the AXI stream handshake wrong, but I'm not sure how. Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Here is also the full version of my code, and here is some of it (it's very messy but please bear with me; this was the only way it met timing requirements):
reg [1:0] can_go=0; //variable to keep track of when the Divider Generator gives back 
                    //the output. Set to 1 when division is complete and set back 
                    //to 0 when a new measurement at counter==1024 is made
reg [15:0] y, y_init, u; 
reg [15:0] x_curr, x_curr0, x_curr1, x_curr2, x_next, x_next2, x_next3;
reg [15:0] e_pre_var, e_next_var, e_next_var1, e_next_var2;
reg [15:0] K_pre, K_next, K_next_num, K_next_denom, one_K_next_sq, K_next_sq; // kalman gain

always@(posedge clk) begin

    if (counter == 9) begin
            y_init = y_measured;
            
    end
    else if (counter == 10) begin
            x_next2 = k_omega*y_init;
            x_next3 = oT*x_next2;
            measured = x_next3;
            $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, x_next2=%d, x_next3=%d", $time, counter, 
    counter1024, x_next2, x_next3);
    end
    else if (counter == 11) begin
            x_next = x_next1 - x_next3; // predict the next state x_n
            e_pre_var = e_pre_var0; // make sure this is a positive number
            can_go = 1;
            $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, x_next=%d, e_pre_var=%d", $time, counter, counter1024, x_next, e_pre_var);   
    end
        
    else if (counter_eq_1024 && can_go == 1) begin             
         
        y = y_measured;
        u = -oT*k_omega*y;
        $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, y=%d, u=%d", $time, counter, counter1024, y, u);
    end
    else if (counter1024 == 1 && can_go == 1) begin
        
        K_next_num = phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var;
        K_next_denom = phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var + s_var;
        M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata = K_next_denom;
        M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata = K_next_num;
        M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tvalid = 1'b1; // send the numerator and denominator values to the Divider Generator
        M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tvalid = 1'b1;
        $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, e_pre_var=%d, K_next_num=%d S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=%d, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata=%d, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata=%d", $time, counter, counter1024, e_pre_var, K_next_num, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata);
        can_go = 0;
        
        if (S_AXIS_IN_tready_kal && S_AXIS_IN_tvalid_kal) begin
            K_next = S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal;
            can_go = 1'b1;
        
           $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, K_next_num=%d, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=%d, phi_sq=%d, e_pre_var=%d", $time, counter, counter1024, K_next_num, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal, phi_sq, e_pre_var);
        end
    end 
    else if (counter1024 == 500 && can_go == 1) begin // jump to 500 to give Divider Generator enough time to finish division
    
        K_next = S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal;
        x_curr0 = 1-K_next;
        x_curr1 = x_curr0*x_next;
        x_curr2 = K_next*y;
        
    end 
    else if (counter1024 == 501 && can_go == 1) begin
        x_curr = x_curr1 + x_curr2; // estimate the current state
        
        x_next = phi*x_curr + u; // predict the next state
        
    end 
    else if (counter1024 == 502 && can_go == 1) begin            
        one_K_next_sq = (1-K_next)*(1-K_next);
        K_next_sq = K_next*K_next;
    end
    else if(counter1024 == 503 && can_go == 1) begin
        e_next_var1 = one_K_next_sq*K_next_num;
        e_next_var2 = K_next_sq*s_var;
        e_next_var = e_next_var1 + e_next_var2;
        
    end
    else if (counter1024 == 504 && can_go == 1) begin

        // make the next values the old values for next cycle
        K_pre = K_next;
        e_pre_var = e_next_var;
 
        
        // Assign the calculated value to the output signal
        M_AXIS_OUT_tdata = x_next;
        
        // Store sampled data in memory
        x_data = x_next;
        
        M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tvalid = 1'b0; // stop data flow to Divider Generator
        M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tvalid = 1'b0;
        can_go = 0;
        
    end
end

Here are the display results:
Time 0 ns: adc_data = 0123
Time 2 ns:          9,          9, y_init= 7900
Time 2 ns:         10,         10, x_next2= 3568, x_next3=22208
Time 2 ns:         11,         11, x_next=58145, e_pre_var=27611
WARNING: 4 ns test_bench.system_i.PS7.processing_system7_0.inst.M_AXI_GP0.master.IF : ARESET_N can't be X/Z after 1 cycle of clock. To downgrade, use <hierarchy_path to VIP>.IF.set_enable_xchecks_to_warn(), or filter using clr_enable_xchecks.
WARNING: 4 ns test_bench.system_i.PS7.processing_system7_0.inst.S_AXI_HP0.slave.IF : ARESET_N can't be X/Z after 1 cycle of clock. To downgrade, use <hierarchy_path to VIP>.IF.set_enable_xchecks_to_warn(), or filter using clr_enable_xchecks.
                   4 else checking line ......1
Warning: [Unisim MMCME2_ADV-20] Input CLKIN1 period and attribute CLKIN1_PERIOD are not same. Instance test_bench.system_i.SignalGenerator.clk_wiz_0.inst.mmcm_adv_inst 
run: Time (s): cpu = 00:00:04 ; elapsed = 00:00:12 . Memory (MB): peak = 2378.973 ; gain = 0.000
xsim: Time (s): cpu = 00:00:05 ; elapsed = 00:00:15 . Memory (MB): peak = 2378.973 ; gain = 0.000
INFO: [USF-XSim-96] XSim completed. Design snapshot 'test_bench_behav' loaded.
INFO: [USF-XSim-97] XSim simulation ran for 15000ns
launch_simulation: Time (s): cpu = 00:00:11 ; elapsed = 00:02:24 . Memory (MB): peak = 2378.973 ; gain = 0.000

and the block diagram:

Here is the main part of my testbench as well (full test bench):
  reg clk = 0;
  reg [13:0] adc_data; // Assuming 14-bit ADC data width
  reg adc_valid = 1'b0; // Start with invalid data
  always #100 clk = ~clk;
  initial begin
    // Reset
    #50;
    adc_valid = 1'b1; // Start providing valid data
    
    // Simulate ADC data
    adc_data = 14'h123; // Example ADC data
    $display("Time %0t: adc_data = %h", $time, adc_data); // Print initial data
    #1000000000; // Simulate for some time
    adc_valid = 1'b0;
    adc_data = 14'h423;
    #50000000;
    adc_valid = 1'b1;
    // Change adc_data to 14'h223
    adc_data = 14'h223; // New ADC data
    $display("Time %0t: adc_data = %h", $time, adc_data); // Print new data
    #100; // Simulate for some more time
  end

Edit:
After removing the block
if (S_AXIS_IN_tready_kal && S_AXIS_IN_tvalid_kal) begin
            K_next = S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal;
            can_go = 1'b1;
        
           $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, K_next_num=%d, 
S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=%d, phi_sq=%d, e_pre_var=%d", $time, counter, 
counter1024, K_next_num, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal, phi_sq, e_pre_var);
        end

the IP started giving outputs.

Are you the same person as account https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/373131/user25028310, who posted similar questions yesterday?

Post a minimal, complete code example directly into the question so we can run a sim.  External links can disappear.

@toolic Yes I'm the same user, it wasn't intentional to open another account here; I had registered with my github account but when I logged out and tried logging in again, there was no option to login with github so I had to create another account. I added the main part of my test bench, I'm not sure if it will work without all other files but thank you for having taken the time to reply even if you decide not to spend more time on this.

Regarding the 2 accounts, you should consider merging them

I compiled the full code link for the kalmanf1ave module, and I get compile errors with 2 different simulators (Cadence and Synopsys).  For example:
Error-[IND] Identifier not declared
  Identifier 'can_go' has not been declared yet. If this error is not 
  expected, please check if you have set `default_nettype to none.

If your Vivado simulator does not give you an error, then there may be a bug with the simulator which is causing the simulation problem you are having.  You should use another simulator.
There are free simulators available on the EDA Playground site, for example.
You should declare can_go as a reg, as follows:
reg [COUNT_WIDTH-1:0]          cycle=0, cycle_next=0;
reg [1:0]                      counter_eq_1024;
reg can_go; 


The simulators also generate several warnings like:
    parameter x_init = 16'b0_00000000000000000001000011000110,  // initial guess for x_0|0 (units of power)
                                                            |
xmvlog: *W,INTOVF : bit overflow during conversion from text [2.5(IEEE)] (16 bits).

Again, if Vivado does not inform you about this type of thing, consider using other simulators.

Thank you so much, after getting rid of this block:
'if (S_AXIS_IN_tready_kal && S_AXIS_IN_tvalid_kal) begin
K_next = S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal;
can_go = 1'b1;
       $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, K_next_num=%d, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=%d, phi_sq=%d, e_pre_var=%d", $time, counter, counter1024, K_next_num, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal, phi_sq, e_pre_var);
    end'

I was able to get an output from the Divider Generator but 'S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal' still gives zero for some reason.

@nisak: You're welcome.  Since this answer fixes problems, go ahead and Accept and Upvote it.  Post a new question with your new code.  As you can see, posting code in a comment is very hard to read.
